# Jahia6.6 deployment error in maven-built module

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, deployment

I am trying to develop a template-set module for a [Jahia](http://www.jahia.com/cms/home/download.html) site.

I used the step-by-step procedure described in the official documentation available here : http://www.jahia.com/cms/home/download/jahia-academy/documentation.default.html?displayTab=technical-documentation "**Templating and Integration Guide**".

Basically, it implies to use an maven [archetype](http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml) to initialize, build and deploy your project on the server. The two first steps are correctly done. It generates the module's skeleton and mandatory files. Then, I can build it to create a .war file.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=http://maven.jahia.org/maven2    
>> [INFO] PROJECT GENERATED

mvn clean install
>> [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

But an error occurs during the deployment.

```
mvn jahia:deploy
>> [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jahia.server:maven-jahia-plugin:2.81:deploy (default-cli) on project test-template-set: 
>> Error while validating deployers:Factory not initialized properly, 
>> you must set the targetServerDirectory variable before calling getInstance ! -> [Help 1]
>> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

The provided [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException) gives me a self explanatory conclusion :

> Unlike many other errors, this exception is not generated by the Maven
>   core itself but by a plugin. The concrete meaning of the exception
>   depends on the plugin so please have a look at its documentation.

So after using a standard procedure described in the Jahia Documentation, the only piece of advice I could find is to have a closer look at it. Welcome to the catch-22 side of life.

I am using Jahia6.6.1.0 community distribution. I found no further clues in the Jahia fora.

I would like to know which step did I miss. Is this a common maven error ? Or is it just a Jahia mandatory file missing ?
A clue to find a "helloworld working module" would be great as well.

Here is the complete trace of the error :

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Test Cooptation template set 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jahia-plugin:2.81:deploy (default-cli) @ test-template-set ---
[INFO] Jahia project structure version is 2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.456s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 25 14:39:19 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/220M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jahia.server:maven-jahia-plugin:2.81:deploy (default-cli) on project test-template-set: Error while validating deployers:
Factory not initialized properly, you must set the targetServerDirectory variabl
e before calling getInstance ! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jahia.server:maven-jahia-plugin:2.81:deploy (default-cli) on project test-template-set: Error while validating deployers
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error while validating deployers
        at org.jahia.utils.maven.plugin.DeployMojo.doValidate(DeployMojo.java:129)
        at org.jahia.utils.maven.plugin.AbstractManagementMojo.execute(AbstractManagementMojo.java:129)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Factory not initialized properly, you must set the targetServerDirectory variable before calling getInstance !
        at org.jahia.configuration.deployers.ServerDeploymentFactory.getInstance(ServerDeploymentFactory.java:74)
        at org.jahia.utils.maven.plugin.DeployMojo.doValidate(DeployMojo.java:127)
        ... 22 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Prerequisites - by Jahia](http://www.jahia.com/community/documentation/jahiapedia/development/module.html) mentions that we should at least adjust the target path to our Apache Tomcat application server and, in case you will build Jahia from sources code and deploy it, the DB connection settings.

The minimal `settings.xml` file for deploying `Jahia` on a `Tomcat` and using `MySQL DBMS` is:

```aml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <localRepository>C:/development/m2repository</localRepository>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>jahiaRepository</id>
            <username>maven</username>
            <privateKey>C:/putty/maven.jahia.org.private</privateKey>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>jahia-mysql</id>
            <properties>
                <jahia.configure.databaseType>mysql</jahia.configure.databaseType>
                <jahia.configure.databaseUrl>jdbc:mysql://localhost/jahia?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;useServerPrepStmts=false</jahia.configure.databaseUrl>
                <jahia.configure.databaseUsername>root</jahia.configure.databaseUsername>
                <jahia.configure.databasePassword>password</jahia.configure.databasePassword>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>jahia-tomcat</id>
            <properties>
                <jahia.deploy.targetServerType>tomcat</jahia.deploy.targetServerType>
                <jahia.deploy.targetServerDirectory>C:/development/apache-tomcat-6.0.32</jahia.deploy.targetServerDirectory>
                <jahia.deploy.targetServerVersion>6</jahia.deploy.targetServerVersion>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>jahia-mysql</activeProfile>
        <activeProfile>jahia-tomcat</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

    <pluginGroups>
        <pluginGroup>org.jahia.server</pluginGroup>
    </pluginGroups>
</settings>
```

I hope this may help.